# Why are my map marker ObjectAnimators getting canceled?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

The app I work on animates map markers after they are added to the screen using ObjectAnimators. The animation replaces the icon with progressively larger or smaller bitmaps. About 20% of the time, it will randomly cancel the animation, leaving it only partially enlarged or shrunk. I know it's getting canceled because a) the animation doesn't complete and b) if I add an `AnimatorListener`, then `onAnimationCancel()` is called in those times.

It doesn't seem to be related to garbage collection, to other pins (it can happen when only one pin is placed on the screen), to other code that runs while the animation is in progress.

They are not set to autoCancel, and even if they were, it wouldn't be triggered because multiple identical animations are not being started.

Any idea at all why this would happen? Has anyone ever seen animations being canceled randomly and unexpectedly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel like an idiot--I finally realized why this was happening!

ObjectAnimators only have a weak reference to their target object.

If you don't maintain a separate reference to the object being animated in some other variable, then sometimes it will be garbage collected before the animation is finished. The next iteration of the ObjectAnimator will attempt to update the object, fail because the target object is null, and then it will cancel the animation.

The solution, then, is simply to ensure you have a variable referencing that object, at least until the animation is complete.

Hope this helps--I'm sure I can't be the only one that's run into this issue!